# Cannot insert when clicking a button in Mysql using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner in web development, I used have an html elements, like textbox and other type of elements, I want to use them as my object and when they have a value and click a button, it will save the value of all the elements in mysql.

I have a code like this, but it cannot be inserted and anything does not happen when clicking a button.
Please help.

PHP:

```
<?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'ytp');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

   if(!$db ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
   }

   $fname = "";
   $mname = "";
   $lname = "";
   $funame = "";
   $cnum = "";
   $bday = "";
   $age = "";
   $add = "";    

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $fname = $_POST['fName'];
   $mname = $_POST['mName'];
   $lname = $_POST['lName'];
   $funame = $_POST['fuName'];
   $cnum = $_POST['Cnumber'];
   $bday = $_POST['bday'];
   $age = $_POST['age'];
   $add = $_POST["address"];       
   }


   $sql = "INSERT INTO employee ".
      "(fName,mName,lName,fuName,cNumber,bDay,Age,Address) ".
      "VALUES ('$fname','$mname','$lname','$funame','$cnum','$bday','$age','$add' )";


    if (! mysqli_query($db , $sql)){
        echo 'Cannot Insert';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Success';
    }

?>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="title">Add User Information</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="php_functions\saveEmployee.php" name="INSERT">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 pr-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Company (disabled)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="" placeholder="Company" value="Benchmark Valuer's Inc.">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 px-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" value="" id="id" name ="id" disabled>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="s.sample@gmail.com" id="email" name ="email">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 pr-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" id="fName" name ="fName">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Middle Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name" id="mName" name ="mName">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" id="lName" name ="lName">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1" hidden>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Fullname</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" id="fuName" name ="fuName"> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 pr-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Contact Number</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number" id="Cnumber" name="Cnumber">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Age</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" id="age" name="age">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Birthday</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Birthday" id="bday" name="bday">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Home Address" id="address" name ="address">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 pr-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="uName">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 px-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="pWord">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>UserType</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0" id="uType">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row" hidden>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Image Path:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="C:\\" id="imageURL">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-fill btn-success" id="btnBrowse">Browse</button>
                <button class="btn btn-fill btn-danger" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML form is closing before submit button. You should close that after submit button and also need to manage hierarchy of opening form tag as below:

```
<form method="POST" action="php_functions\saveEmployee.php" name="INSERT">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 pr-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Company (disabled)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="" placeholder="Company" value="Benchmark Valuer's Inc.">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 px-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" value="" id="id" name ="id" disabled>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="s.sample@gmail.com" id="email" name ="email">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 pr-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" id="fName" name ="fName">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Middle Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name" id="mName" name ="mName">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" id="lName" name ="lName">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1" hidden>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Fullname</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" id="fuName" name ="fuName"> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 pr-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Contact Number</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number" id="Cnumber" name="Cnumber">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Age</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" id="age" name="age">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Birthday</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Birthday" id="bday" name="bday">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Home Address" id="address" name ="address">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 pr-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="uName">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 px-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="pWord">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-md-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>UserType</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0" id="uType">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row" hidden>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Image Path:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="C:\\" id="imageURL">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-fill btn-success" id="btnBrowse">Browse</button>
                <button class="btn btn-fill btn-danger" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

the form has been closed before the submit button.

[image]

the `</form>` tag should be placed after the `<div class="card-footer">...</div>`.
please try it. hope it will help.